# How do I numpy-ize a Service node or a Client node to manage Request or Response containing numpy array?

Tags: ros, rospy, array, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to transmit a numpy array in a response of a service but I have some trouble to convert it in the appropriate type. I saw the numpy_msg tutorials it works fine for messages but I don't get how to make it work for request/response of services.

Thanks to you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11684/how-do-i-numpy-ize-a-service-node-or-a-client-node-to-manage-request-or-response-containing-numpy-array-?/) by [sylou](https://answers.ros.org/users/1422/sylou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The numpy serialization/deserialization stubs has been generated in the corresponding PKG.srv.*; So one can probably override the default serialize() deserialize() in the same manner as numpy_msg does. Take the rospy_tutorial/005_AddTwoInts for an example,
You'll probably need to add these new lines:

```
import rospy.numpy_msg
AddTwoInts._request_class = rospy.numpy_msg.numpy_msg(AddTwoIntsRequest)
AddTwoInts._response_class = rospy.numpy_msg.numpy_msg(AddTwoIntsResponse)
AddTwoIntsRequest = rospy.numpy_msg.numpy_msg(AddTwoIntsRequest)
AddTwoIntsResponse= rospy.numpy_msg.numpy_msg(AddTwoIntsResponse)
```

I haven't got a chance to test the code myself, but hope this give you some idea.

---

Originally posted by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) with karma: 91 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0